# Regex pattern to have only one dot and match integer and decimal numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm struggling with creating proper regex pattern to match such strings:

```
"3" // true
"3." // true
"3.1" // true
"3.22" // true
```

And such strings should fail matching:

```
"3.." // false
"3.222" // false
```

My current regex `/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})*$/` matches only decimal numbers. I've tried several updates to it but cannot accept all rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the decimal part optional + you forgot to put `\` before first `d`, and remove `*` from the decimal part.

```
/^\d+(\.\d{0,2})?$/
  ^             ^
```

Comment: try in console - `/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?*$/.test('1.')` => `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?*$/: Nothing to repeat`

Comment: Your updated variant behaves the same as my - `/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/.test('1.')` => `false` but I need `true`.

Comment: It is because of the `{1,2}`, replace with `{0,2}`.

Comment: @Kosmetika: `3.` is valid decimal number? Not sure, but as @stribizhevsaid, `{0,2}`.